# Arbitrary union

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How do I find the subsets of R for 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(-2+\frac1n, 1+\frac1n\right)
$$

I know the answer is (-2,2) but how do I get there? I have an exam i'd appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: This is a rather **specific** union, not an arbitrary one...

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  That's not correct.  When $n=1$, the interval is $(-1, 2)$.  There's work to do at the left end of the union.

Comment: @RobertShore Misread the question. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What is the value for $n=1$? $n=2$? what happens when $n$ is large? See a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $x$ is in the big union, then we can find some $n_0$ so that $x \in (-2 + \frac{1}{n_0}, 1 + \frac{1}{n_0} ) $ so that

$$ -2 < -2 + \frac{1}{n_0} < x < 1 + \frac{1}{n_0} < 2 $$

Now, if $x \in (-2,2)$ you may apply the archimidean principle to show there is the interval you are looking for and so it better lie on the union.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you!